# view can't find variable (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following action in my controller:

```
public function viewPost($id)
{
    $current_post = forum_post::with('replies')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('forumViewPost',['currentPost', $current_post]);
}
```

Then I have the following view:

```
 @extends('layout.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">

        <div class="nk-gap-2"></div>

        <ul class="nk-forum nk-forum-topic">
            <li>
                <div class="nk-forum-topic-author">
                    <img src="assets/images/avatar-2-sm.jpg" alt="Kurt Tucker">
                    <div class="nk-forum-topic-author-name" title="Kurt Tucker">
                        <a href="#">{{$currentPost->nickname}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nk-forum-topic-author-role">
                        Member
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-forum-topic-content">
                    {{$currentPost->content}}
                </div>
                <div class="nk-forum-topic-footer">
              <span class="nk-forum-topic-date">June 19,
              2017</span> <span class="nk-forum-action-btn"><a href="#forum-reply" class="nk-anchor"> Reply</a></span>
                    <span class="nk-forum-action-btn"><a href="#"> Spam</a></span>
                    <span class="nk-forum-action-btn"><span class="nk-action-heart liked"><span class="num">1</span>
              Like</span></span>
                </div>
            </li>
            @foreach($currentPost->replies as $replies)

            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endsection
```

now when I run this. I get the following error:

```
Undefined variable: currentPost
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: one tip, stick to one variable naming style. if you want to use **camelCase**, stick with it. That's one way of avoiding this kind of issue :) (by doing so, you could use `compact` method to pass variables to the view with ease)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `[]` you may write this `['currentPost' => $current_post]`

All

```
public function viewPost($id)
{
    $current_post = forum_post::with('replies')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('forumViewPost',['currentPost' => $current_post]);
}
```

Comment: You are wellcome! It happens)

Answer (score 0):

You can also you `compact('');` and as  Wreigh mentioned change `$current_post` to `$currectPost`

```
public function viewPost($id)
{
  $currentPost = forum_post::with('replies')->where('id', $id)->get();
  return view('forumViewPost', compact('currentPost'));
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work, change `$current_post` into `$currentPost`. :)

Comment: yep, I've noticed because I was going to write the same answer lol